# How to create an Ubuntu container with lxc-ruby

Tags: ruby, lxc

I am trying to create a container in Ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS with this code but as result I get false:

```
require 'lxc'
c = LXC::Container.new 'foo'
c.create('/usr/lib/lxc/templates/lxc-ubuntu') => false
```

Probably I am using a wrong template. Do you see any error or do you know where is the default template?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the full path of the LXC template. `c.create ('ubuntu')` should work well.